# How do I add Ubuntu Music store to Rhythmbox?

Tags: 11.04, rhythmbox, music, ubuntu-one

I've checked in the plugins and i can't seem to get the Ubuntu one music store in Rhythmbox. I'm not a fan of Banshee FYI. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed the plug in from the Ubuntu software center then go into Rhythmbox's preferences and the plugins and see if the Ubuntu one music store is enabled there.

Comment: Cheers, sorted it now.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark as best answer?